# Differential equations of harmonic oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have 2 questions:
[image]

1. Write down the Euler-Lagrange equation: my equation is $\ddot{q}+\frac{\omega_{0}}{Q}\dot{q}+m\omega_{0}^2q = 0$ Is it correct?
2. Show that if Q not equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ there are two independent solutions of the equation of motion each having the form: [image]

I cannot show that and I do not know why the two independent solutions have the form of real part. Why are they both cosine. Can you help me?